# MouseDragging in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drag-and-drop

What i want this code to do is when i press and drag the red ball on the screen, i want it to move with the mouse cursor, this code does the job and is partly taken from Sun code, so it is suppose to be efficient, but yet if i move the mouse too fast, it stops draging the mouse...

how do i overcome this?

```
    public class SwingPaintDemo3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    } 
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private int X = 0;
    private int Y = 0;
    private int R = 20;


         public MyPanel() {

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if ((X<=e.getX() && X+R>=e.getX()) && ( Y<=e.getY() && Y+R>=e.getY())) moveVertex(e.getX(),e.getY());
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if ((X<=e.getX() && X+R>=e.getX()) && ( Y<=e.getY() && Y+R>=e.getY())) moveVertex(e.getX(),e.getY());
            }
        });

    }

    private void moveVertex(int x, int y) {
        int OFFSET = 1;
        if ((X!=x) || (Y!=y)) {
            repaint(X,Y,R+OFFSET,R+OFFSET);
            X=x-10;
            Y=y-10;
            repaint(X,Y,R+OFFSET,R+OFFSET);
        } 
    }


    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250,200);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);       
        g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(X,Y,R,R);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(X,Y,R,R);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem occurs because the event handler Java's thread isn't fast enough to process a mouseDragged event when you move the mouse too fast. So say you have the mouse pointer at the center of the circle, but you move it really fast for some directions, thus the mouseDragged event is fired only when the mouse is outside the circle area, so the mouse pointer is not "with the cicle" anymore.

A fix for this problem is to use a boolean variable with the mouseButton status, if the mouse is clicked inside the circle, you'll make the circle goes with the mouse anywhere! If the guy releases the mouse button your mouse just moves.

```
    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        ...
        private boolean holdedInsideCircle = false;


           public MyPanel() {

               addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    if ((X<=e.getX() && X+R>=e.getX()) && ( Y<=e.getY() && Y+R>=e.getY()))
                        moveVertex(e.getX(),e.getY());
                        holdedInsideCircle = true;
                   }
                   @Override
                   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                       //Doesn't matter where, if the mouse button is released
                       holdedInsideCircle = false;
                   }
               });


               addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                       //if ((X<=e.getX() && X+R>=e.getX()) && ( Y<=e.getY() && Y+R>=e.getY()))
                       if(holdedInsideCircle)
                           moveVertex(e.getX(),e.getY());
                   }
               });

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this variant.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingPaintDemo3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private int X = 0;
    private int Y = 0;
    private int R = 20;
    private boolean isDrag = false;

    public MyPanel() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if ((X<=e.getX() && X+R>=e.getX()) && ( Y<=e.getY() && Y+R>=e.getY())) {
                    moveVertex(e.getX(),e.getY());
                    isDrag = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                isDrag = false;
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (isDrag) moveVertex(e.getX(),e.getY());
            }
        });
    }

    private void moveVertex(int x, int y) {
        int OFFSET = 1;
        if ((X!=x) || (Y!=y)) {
            repaint(X,Y,R+OFFSET,R+OFFSET);
            X=x-10;
            Y=y-10;
            repaint(X,Y,R+OFFSET,R+OFFSET);
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250,200);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(X,Y,R,R);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(X,Y,R,R);
    }
}
```

Comment: The constraint checks in the mouse dragged method were not able to keep up with the movement of the mouse.  ;)